# Vb Net ClickOnce - Application cannot be started. Contact the application vendor

Tags: clickonce

We are encountering an unusual issue with our in-house developed VB.NET applications (version 2022) deployed via ClickOnce. After some time, on certain computers, the applications fail to launch and display the following error: "Application cannot be started. Contact the application vendor." The applications function correctly upon initial installation.

Our current workaround for this problem is to delete the contents of the C:\Users\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0 folder and reinstall each ClickOnce application when the issue arises. It's worth noting that both the applications and the computers are consistently shut down properly.

In an attempt to address this issue, we have increased the cache size in the registry under [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Deployment] by modifying the "OnlineAppQuotaUsageEstimate" value.

Our publication folders are stored on a Synology NAS server. Despite our efforts, we are still in search of a permanent solution to resolve this problem. Any assistance or guidance in finding a lasting resolution would be greatly appreciated